# Location of SCP on server 2012 R2 Essentials after migration

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2012-r2, outlook, microsoft-office-365

I have migrated from SBS 2008 with Exchange 2007 to Server 2012 R2 Essentials, and Exchange Online (Office 365).

When users log into Outlook, Outlook still attempts to connect to an old url, that it is discovering through SCP. The exact wording is:

"Attempting URL xxx.xxxx.com.au/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml found through SCP"

Where is the location of this SCP object on the 2012 R2 server? I can't find it inside AD anywhere, is it possibly somehow on the Exchange Online server?

(I discovered it was using this old url while running the Outlook Test Configuration)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result of my unusual setup, this was a bit more complicated than Sembee posted above,

I joined the 2012 R2 Essentials to the domain, making it an AD Domain Controller. So all the Exchange 2007 objects carried over to the 2012 server. These objects, it turns out, seem to be "hidden", and cannot be found using Active Directory sites and services - more specifically inside Services.

I then synced 2012 R2 to Azure, and migrated Exchange 2007 to Exchange Online. I then demoted the SBS 2008 and removed it from the domain entirely, as it is a VM, and we are migrating all our VMs to AZURE.

Unfortunately all the old SBS 2008 and Exchange 2007 objects are still a part of AD on the 2012 Server, even though Excahnge 2007 is not compatible with 2012.. Meaning, as I understand it, that these objects are not easily accessible... specifically the SCP object.

So the solution:

I managed to find a script to find the SCP via powershell -

```
$obj = @()

$ADDomain = Get-ADDomain | Select DistinguishedName
$DSSearch = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$DSSearch.Filter = '(&(objectClass=serviceConnectionPoint)(|    (keywords=67661d7F-8FC4-4fa7-BFAC-E1D7794C1F68)(keywords=77378F46-2C66-4aa9-A6A6-3E7A48B19596)))'
$DSSearch.SearchRoot = 'LDAP://CN=Configuration,'+$ADDomain.DistinguishedName
$DSSearch.FindAll() | %{

$ADSI = [ADSI]$_.Path
$autodiscover = New-Object psobject -Property @{
Server = [string]$ADSI.cn
Site = $adsi.keywords[0]
DateCreated = $adsi.WhenCreated.ToShortDateString()
AutoDiscoverInternalURI = [string]$adsi.ServiceBindingInformation
}
    $obj += $autodiscover

}

Write-Output $obj | Select Server,Site,DateCreated,AutoDiscoverInternalURI | ft -AutoSize$obj = @()
```

This revealed the objects that were still inside AD somewhere, and I was then able to use AD Administrative Centre to run a "global catalog search" for all objects that were under the name of the SCP, and from those results, I was able to find the SCP object and delete it. Strangely enough, right clicking and selecting "Locate" fires an error saying location cannot be found.. Sort of expected due to the lack of compatibility. However luckily, deleting the object from here, works.

I came upon this problem, as our all our Outlooks clients started to fire a certificate issue when logging in, even though we were connecting directly to Exchange Online / Office 365, and not to a local server.

Here is the link to the site where I found this script:

http://vanhybrid.com/2012/11/21/retrieving-exchange-autodiscover-scp-information-from-ad-via-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove Exchange 2007 properly, using add/remove programs? 
It should have removed all of the entries.

It is seen in ADSIEDIT in the following location:
CN=Autodiscover,CN=Protocols,CN=servername,CN=Servers,CN=Exchange Administrative Group,CN=Administrative Groups,CN=Your Organization,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services

Where servername is the name of the old Exchange server and your org is the org name.

Comment: Hey @Sembee , it is a bit complicated - I joined the server 2012 R2 machine to the domain, and added the AD role to it - so it took the current AD which included the Exchange 2007 data.. I then Migrated the Excahnge server to Excahnge online, after syncing via Azure. I then dcpromo'd the old server but left Exchange 2007 on it just in case.. Perhaps I should have uninstalled it at that point to remove any objects in AD? Too late unfortunately for that... :) So now its a manual process of removing any remnants left over in the AD...

Using ADSIEDIT did not work - see my answer below. Thanks!